# You're receiving this email because you reached a Stack Overflow community milestone

Tags: support, bug, email

Today I received an email from do-not-reply at stackoverflow.email with the subject:

> Reputation values have changed across Stack Overflow

It was about:

> **We’ve increased the value for upvotes to questions**
>   We doubled the reputation points earned from getting an upvote to a question to 10 points. This makes it equal to the reputation points earned from getting an upvote to an answer.

That looks like a *company announcement* to me, or perhaps a *feature update*.

It told me why I was sent that email at the end:

> You're receiving this email because you reached a Stack Overflow community milestone.

Um, no I haven't, not that I've been made aware of anyway.

Let's check my email preferences:

[image]

As you can see, I have **not** subscribed to the "Features & Announcements" emails, so it appears to be a bug that I was sent that email.

Was there a problem with the selection of which users to send that email to?

Comment: yes got the same and I thought it's probably "trusted user" here : https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges?tab=milestone but it seems not based on your Rep

Comment: or maybe it's the *and more* inside the "Community Milestones" you are setting to ON

Comment: @TemaniAfif How about "reputation" in that same sentence ....

Comment: @rene with my non-good english skills I understand it as: you will get notified for bounties *and* reputation (like for example when you reach 100K (I got such mail)) *and* more stuffs. Maybe such mail is included in the *more stuffs* [it's a simple guess btw]

Comment: @TemaniAfif I don't think so, because the *and more* is then switched to "Off" in the "Research" section :)

Comment: Trying to not kick in a wide open door: it is kinda important that SO users suspend their expectation of normalcy while the new CEO and his team try to make the site grow. Lord knows what they'll think of next when they get no results.   We only have to out-last the VC people, they are not especially good at patience.  Meanwhile just don't let them abuse this so easily, set the preference to Off.

Comment: @HansPassant Not to be offtopic but I do find it odd this weird attempt to make the site grow when it's the established users which give the site life while 90% of users really use SO as a sort of knowledge base. I don't see the logic of trying to push those who manage and give the answers a reason leave in the hope for even more questions.

Comment: @HansPassant But then I won't get to hear about the [New swag for Stack Overflow's 10th birthday: wear-ables or desk-ables?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314941/232762) I was so looking forward to getting a plush unicorn, or maybe a rubber duck, or even a T-shirt would be nice.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Here are some fine ASCII Unicorns to comfort you: https://www.asciiart.eu/mythology/unicorns (also very suitable for text-email-swag) ;)

Comment: It's not related to reputation change: I've never asked a question anywhere on the network, so I know my rep didn't change, and I got the same email with everything but "Community Milestones" turned off. Maybe just being present when they decided to make optimizing for sand explicit is itself the milestone.